# Verify that correct method was passed in a function call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delegates, rhino-mocks

My test class takes 2 objects in its constructor, a data loader and a class that consumes the data returned from the data loader.

The data loader interface has 2 functions, LoadCompanies() and LoadEmployees(), both of which take an int parameter and return an IEnumerable.

How can I verify that the method under test passes LoadCompanies() and NOT LoadEmployees() into the data consumer class?

Here is my code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestingFunctionalParameters_UT
{
    [Test]
    public void Correct_Loader_Method_is_Used()
    {
        const int userId = 1;
        var companies = new[] { "c1", "c2" };
        var dataLoader = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITestDataLoader>();
        var dataConsumer = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataConsumerClass>();

        var testObject = new TestClass(dataLoader, dataConsumer);

        dataConsumer.Expect(fc => fc.LoadIt(Arg<Func<IEnumerable<string>>>.Is.TypeOf)).Return(true);

        //TODO: validate that correct dataloader function was called...
        //dataLoader.Expect(dl => dl.LoadCompanies(userId)).Return(companies);

        var result = testObject.Run(userId);

        Assert.That(result, Is.True);
        dataLoader.VerifyAllExpectations();
        dataConsumer.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    private readonly ITestDataLoader dataLoader;
    private readonly IDataConsumerClass funcClass;

    public TestClass(ITestDataLoader dataLoader, IDataConsumerClass funcClass)
    {
        this.dataLoader = dataLoader;
        this.funcClass = funcClass;
    }

    public bool Run(int userId)
    {
        Func<IEnumerable<string>> loadFn = () => dataLoader.LoadCompanies(userId);
        return funcClass.LoadIt(loadFn);
    }
}

public interface ITestDataLoader
{
    IEnumerable<string> LoadCompanies(int userId);
    IEnumerable<string> LoadEmployees(int userId);
}

public interface IDataConsumerClass
{
    bool LoadIt(Func<IEnumerable<string>> load);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I would rather make the parameter's type ITestDataLoader and call the desired method.

Comment: I assume that this is a simplified example of a more complicated delegate injection pattern.

Comment: You are correct Steve.  I found that I was doing the same thing over and over to create a report: load data (different method every time), used another object to return a few items and then used a 3rd object to generate a report (different one every time).  So I refactored: pulled the common logic into a private method taking in functions or actions as parameters. I then turned this private method into another class with its own tests.  It really simplified the testing burden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**Edit**: I am assuming that your example is a simplified one, and your actual implementation is an attempt to test a delegate injection pattern)

Maybe you could write your test like this? (**Edited to actually compile**)

```
[Test]
public void Correct_Loader_Method_is_Used()
{
    const int userId = 1;
    var companies = new[] { "c1", "c2" };
    var dataLoader = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITestDataLoader>();
    var dataConsumer = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataConsumerClass>();

    var testObject = new TestClass(dataLoader, dataConsumer);

    dataConsumer.Expect(fc => fc.LoadIt(Arg<Func<IEnumerable<string>>>.Matches(x => x().Any()))).Return(true);

    //validate that correct dataloader function was called...
    dataLoader.Expect(dl => dl.LoadCompanies(userId)).Return(companies);
    // Fails if you uncomment this line
    //dataLoader.Expect(dl => dl.LoadEmployees(userId)).Return(companies);

    var result = testObject.Run(userId);

    Assert.That(result, Is.True);
    dataLoader.VerifyAllExpectations();
    dataConsumer.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Basically the Matches() constraint will try execute the method, and if it tries to call LoadEmployees(), RhinoMocks will complain because it doesn't have a defined mock.

**Update: Handling `Action<T>` delegates**

This might be a little less robust, but for `Action<T>`s:

```
public interface IDataConsumerClass
{
    bool LoadIt(Func<IEnumerable<string>> load);
    bool ExecuteIt<T>(Action<T> execute);
}

//...

dataConsumer.Expect(fc => fc.ExecuteIt(Arg<Action<int>>.Matches(x => ActionWrapper(x, userId)))).Return(true);

//...

private bool ActionWrapper<T>(Action<T> action, T arg)
{
    action(arg);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Steve, That is what I was looking for... figuring out a way to get the test to make the dataLoader call.  I tried to test with your suggestion but the code does not build. I get the error "A lambda method with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree".  I am not savvy enough to understand what that means.

Comment: Fixed it up.  The trick is to coerce the return value of the method you are testing into a bool.  I used IEnumerable<T>.Any() to do that.  You just need to make sure your mocked return value returns at least one value.

Comment: That's the ticket!!  Does "You just need to make sure your mocked return value returns at least one value" mean I may run into problems  when another parameter is an Action<> instead of a Func<>?  Maybe I am misunderstanding - I will test it you in a bit.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You might.  I'll have to think about it for the Action<> case.  The thing here is that we are really tricking RhinoMocks into doing something that it wasn't designed to do.  Matching() has a different use, in general, so it needs a `true` value to continue executing.

Comment: Actually, the signature for the method under test takes in both a Func<T> AND an Action<T> parameter, so the ExecuteIt() won't really work.  I tried playing around with "Is" instead of "Matches" but cannot seem to figure out a trick to return a bool.

Comment: I tried your ActionWrapper [somewhat] like this:

dataConsumer.Expect(fc=>fc.LoadIt(Arg<Action<int>>.Matches(y=>ActionWrapper(y(0))) 

and defined the following:

private bool ActionWrapper(Action<int> action)
{
   action();
   return true;
}

but the compiler did not like the private method or the lambda expression.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you're working with now?

Comment: Changed to Action<T>, but you need to get more rep so we can move this to a chat. :)

Comment: That did it Steve.  I wasn't passing the userId parameter into ActionWrapper.  Thanks for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: I hope I marked it correctly.  Let me know if I didn't - I am new to stack overflow...

Answer (score 1):

You could create companies and employees classes

```
class Company
{
    public Company(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Do the same for employees and then define your interface like this

```
public interface ITestDataLoader   
{   
    IEnumerable<Company> LoadCompanies(int userId);   
    IEnumerable<Employee> LoadEmployees(int userId);   
}
```

Now companies and employees cannot be confused any more.

---

EDIT:

If you have a lot of cases like that, you could create a common base class

```
class NamedItem
{
    public NamedItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

class Company : NamedItem
{
    public Company(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}

class Employee : NamedItem
{
    public Employee (string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Oliver, making separate classes is more work than is warranted for this problem.  I just used IEnumerable<string> for an example - it could have been any  methods with the same signature.  I just wanted a way to verify the right call was made.  Thanks though.

Comment: My solution tries to avoid a possible error from the start, instead of guaranteeing the right behavoir by tests. But I agree, it is more complicated.